# Google OAuth forcing verification and cannot undo

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

Doing some development work to implement Google Sign in and had gotten to the OAuth Consent Screen.  I had uploaded a random image for the Application Logo, not realizing that doing this now forces you to submit the consent for verification, which the terms say could take up to several weeks.

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to undo this application image, or to start over withe the Consent process by deleting it, etc.

Is there a way to get this process back to the point where it does not need verification - especially when just in the development phase?

Open a new google email account and start over that way?  Seems like there should be a way to get over this just for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a new gmail account to start over. Your application is associated with a Google Cloud Project. That project has an OAuth Consent Screen configuration [1], which is what you used to upload the icon/logo.

The easiest path forward, assuming your application is still in development, is to create a new Google Cloud Project [2] and use the OAuth credentials generated in that project in your app configuration.

Here [3] is an example of how you would configure your OAuth client ID in a web application using the Google Sign-in SDK.

[1] https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849

[2] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project

[3] https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web